# Execute Button Method

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to execute a Tkinter `ttk` Button method while the button is pressed, meaning I want the method to keep executing when the button is pressed and stop when I release it, but i can't quite figure it out. Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class stuff (object):

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title("Grid Master")
        master.frame_1 = ttk.Frame(master)
        master.frame_1.pack()
        master.configure(background = "#FFFFFF")

        self.button = ttk.Button(master, text = 'Press', command = self.callback)
        self.button.pack()

    def callback(self):
        print ("Hello world")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    loop = stuff(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see in the code that the method only prints `"Hello world"` and I want this function to execute and keep going, printing `Hello world` until I release the button.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code block? It's quite important for Python...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the indentation !

Comment: Now I see it properly indeed. :-)

Comment: @mhawke fixed the indentation..

Comment: Take a look at the Button `repeatinterval` and `repeatdelay` parameters. http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html

Comment: @PM2Ring Note that only Tkinter buttons have these options, ttk buttons do not ([source](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html))

Comment: tryed it i get the following error 'File "c:\python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2122, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-repeatdelay"'

Comment: Thanks, @fhdrsdg. I don't use tkinter much - I prefer GTK. But I guess that doesn't help Omera...

Comment: Would a "press to start", "press again to stop" functionality be adequate?

Comment: @PM 2Ring   nop, coz iam designing a program that controls a quadcopter

Comment: I've tried the repeatinterval and repeatdelay widget option and they're not working, any suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry to have mislead you, Omera. As fhdrsdg said earlier, those options only work on standard Tkinter buttons, not on ttk buttons. So change your code to use a Tkinter button instead of the ttk button.

Comment: well is there any way to do it on ttk ? I've written my program on ttk !

Comment: @Omera: yes, look at the answers - the one by [fhdrsdg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29824277/21945) is particularly nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `root.after()` to repeatedly schedule a job to perform the required task. Note that I have changed the button event to activate when the button is pressed, and to terminate the "after" job when the button is released.

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    # Python 2, probably
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk

class stuff (object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._master = master
        master.title("Grid Master")
        master.frame_1 = ttk.Frame(master)
        master.frame_1.pack()
        master.configure(background = "#FFFFFF")

        self.button = ttk.Button(master, text = 'Press')
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.button_pressed)
        self.button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.button_released)
        self.button.pack()

        self.hello_world_frequency = 1    # milliseconds 

    def hello_world(self):
        print ("Hello world")
        self._job = self._master.after(self.hello_world_frequency, self.hello_world)

    def button_pressed(self, event):
        print ("Button down")
        self.hello_world()

    def button_released(self, event):
        print ("Button released")
        self._master.after_cancel(self._job)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    loop = stuff(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Rinzler: It is `Tkinter` on my system, but would be `tkinter` for the OP, so thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom repeating ttk button class that inherits from `ttk.Button` but adds basic repeating functionality.

Try this. you can use it like

```
self.button = RepeatButton(master, text='Press', command=self.callback)
```

and you can set the `repeatdelay` and `repeatinterval` arguments, which default to 300 and 100.

```
class RepeatButton(ttk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.callback = kwargs.pop('command', None)
        self.repeatinterval = kwargs.pop('repeatinterval', 100)
        self.repeatdelay = kwargs.pop('repeatdelay', 300)

        ttk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        if self.callback:
            self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.click)
            self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)

    def click(self, event=None):
        self.callback()
        self.after_id = self.after(self.repeatdelay, self.repeat)

    def repeat(self):
        self.callback()
        self.after_id = self.after(self.repeatinterval, self.repeat)

    def release(self, event=None):
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

Comment: This is nice. Same method as my answer, but packaged up in a reusable class +1.

Comment: @mhawke Thanks, yours works nice too. It might be more self-explanatory than mine, which could be more useful to the OP. I actually started out making something like that too but then I found [this](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/sk1-0.9.3.tar.gz/sk1-0.9.3/src/sk1sdk/tcl/repeater.tcl) which gave me the idea to put it in a class.